# Sorting by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, search, union

In my application I'm performing a keyword search on two different tables and on two different column names. I want to combine the `movies.title` and the `people.title` so that I can sort all of them together alphabetically. Currently i merge my two queries and the results come back first with the movies and then with the people.

```
  public function get_from_keyword($keyword){

        $movie_query = $this->db
        ->select('id, title, release_year')
        ->from('movies')
        ->like('movies.title', $keyword)
        ->where('movies.id IS NOT NULL', null)
        ->get()
        ->result();

        $person_query = $this->db
        ->select('name, person_id')
        ->from('people')
        ->like('name', $keyword)
        ->get()
        ->result();

        $merged_queries = array_merge($movie_query, $person_query);
        return $merged_queries;

    }
```

I'm not sure if I need to dynamically alter one of the column names in the `SELECT` query in order to merge them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use an "AS" to name both the movies.title and the people.name fields the same like:

```
   $person_query = $this->db
    ->select('name', 'MySortTitle') // AS
    ->select('person_id')
    ->from('people')
    ->like('name', $keyword)
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

And the same for the movie query:

```
    $movie_query = $this->db
    ->select('title', 'MySortTitle') // AS
    ->select('id, release_year')
    ->from('movies')
    ->like('movies.title', $keyword)
    ->where('movies.id IS NOT NULL', null)
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

Then sort the merged array by MySortTitle.